# Is the integral $\int_{2}^{\infty} \frac{1}{\log(x^2)}\,dx$ convergent or divergent?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, improper-integrals

How can I see if this integral:
$$\int_{2}^{\infty} \frac{1}{\log(x^2)}\,dx$$ is convergent or divergent,
cause I try to resolve the integral and I saw this is a special type of integral,
can you guys help me?
PS: I know that to check if is convergent or divergent I need to do this $$\lim_{t\to\infty}\int_{2}^{t} \frac{1}{\log(x^2)}\,dx$$

Comment: Hint: $$
\frac{1}{{\log (x^2 )}} = \frac{1}{{2\log x}} > \frac{1}{{2x}}
$$ for $x\geq 2$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a good start that you look at the definition of improper integrals. But in general, it is not very useful when the integrand has no easy antiderivative.

What people usually do is using the comparison principle:

> If $0\le f(x)\le g(x)$ on $[a,\infty)$ then
> $$
> \int_a^\infty g(x)\,dx<\infty \Rightarrow \int_a^\infty f(x)\,dx<\infty
> $$
> and
> $$
> \int_a^\infty f(x)\,dx \textrm{ divergent } \Rightarrow \int_a^\infty g(x)\,dx \textrm{ divergent }
> $$

This principle allows you to look at some easy integrals that you have already known whether it is convergent or not; and all you need is to *compare* your integral with the easy one.

In your case, observe that $\frac{1}{\log(x^2)}\ge \frac{1}{2x}$ on $[2,\infty)$.

Also, to do such problems, you should know when the following integral is convergent:
$$
\int_1^\infty \frac{1}{x^p}\,dx
$$
which is assumed to be the *a priori* knowledge since you need some easy integral to compare with.

Answer (score 5):

**Hint:** If $x\geqslant2$, then$$\frac1{\log(x^2)}=\frac1{2\log(x)}\geqslant\frac1{2x}.$$